# How to set up keyserver and port permanently

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gpg

I have corporate firewall which blocks default port for apt-key. So each time I add PPA, I have to interrupt gpg (which hangs) and receive missed keys manually setting port 80. I created script which retrieves missed keys for me, but this solution is still far from ideal.

```
$ cat /usr/local/sbin/get-keys 
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy=$http_proxy --recv-keys $@
```

I'd like to set up apt-key to use port 80 by default, without having to import missing keys manually.